# PHP, loop through dynamic array by count

Tags: php, arrays

So I am working on a JQuery Step Form. It is being populated with dynamic information from the database. I have a particular list of items that is 21 items in the array. I would like to break these down into groups of 5 or 6 per step, so the form isn't so long.

I know I could use `array_slice` for example, but since this list is dynamic, I don't know how many there will always be. It will kind of be paginated in a sense but I don't need pagination links and such. Just a way to return 5 items, then 5 items and if the last iteration only has 2 items then that is it.

So for example:

```
$array = ( 
  array(
    "name" => "Peter Parker",
    "alterego" => "Spiderman",
  ),
  array(
    "name" => "Clark Kent",
    "alterego" => "Superman",
  ), 
  array(
    "name" => "Bruce Wayne",
    "alterego" => "Batman",
  ),
);
```

And then I want to break this down to only list 2 items per group.

Comment: Array_chunk? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Yes @Andreas, this is correct. I mentioned you in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for example:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 5);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // display form for these 5 values
}
```

Comment: This is it! @Andreas commented the idea but this is the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5159168/andreas)' initial advice is great. Maybe here, we might want to design some callback functions based on the pagination sizes that we wish to have:

```
array_slice($array, getChunkStart($array), getChunkLength($array));
```

or if we just look for a specific column size:

```
array_chunk($array, sizeof(array_column($array, "column_key")));
```